# A book or paper on Fermi glasses

Tags: solid-state-physics, resource-recommendations

Can anybody recommend a good book treating the subject of [Fermi glasses](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=fermi+glass)?

A good review paper, preferably something relatively modern, would also be welcome. I know of Anderson's paper ("The Fermi glass: theory and experiment", Comm. Solid State Phys, 1970), but can't even find the journal any more.

Comment: Are you looking for Anderson's paper, or do you really want something different?

Comment: Does [this](http://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.15.2384) help to some extent?

Comment: Thanks for your replies.
Danu - something different
TDS - I found that, but I haven't got access, and its 1977! :) I was thinking about something more up to date.